# Build error after fresh install of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I just did a fresh install of Visual Studio 2010 Premium, and when I loaded up a project, I am getting this error.

> A problem occurred while trying to set the "References" parameter for the IDE's in-process compiler. Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

When I load it up on someone else's copy of Visual Studio 2010, they aren't getting this issue. Any ideas what's causing this? I have tried copying the References folder in C:Program Files to C:\Program Files(x86), and that didn't help.

Comment: Yeah it sounds like your missing a library, load the *run prompt* and type either `wuapp` (Vista and Higher) `wupdmgr` (XP) and check for all the updates that are available.

Comment: Alright! That seemed to have fixed the problem. Thank you very much!